# Find the smallest absolute element in each row of a matrix

Tags: matrix

```
m = {{3, 12, -7, 1}, {16, 7, 2, 9}, {5, 3, 0, -6}, {8, 1, -4, 17}}
```

write a procedural programme and functional programme to find the smallest absolute element in each row of the matrix.

Comment: What about Min /@ Abs[m]?

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem to me. Do you have either answer? Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes i tried it with map.its easy with functional programming

Comment: m={-,-,-,-}:
Map[Min, Abs[m]]       like this one .

Comment: If you already knew this functional solution, you should have mentioned it in your question. Otherwise you are just repeating my comment.

Comment: sorry .after write down question here i go to try this question and i find the solution with functional programming.so when i again check the result on this page i find the same answer as you reply above.BTW thanks for your answer

Comment: Is this procedural enough?
Table[Min[m[[i]]], {i, Length[m]}]

Comment: Thanks.this one is enough

Answer (score 1):

For functional programming (I think so):

```
TakeSmallestBy[Abs, 1] /@ m
```

> ```
> {{1}, {2}, {0}, {1}}
> ```

For procedural programming: left for others.